# is there a way to block questions where user votes is below x

Tags: discussion

Many questions by new users are poor.

The currency on SE is votes, many new visitors ask questions which are closed because of poor quality or they don't upvote or mark as answered meaning we don't get 'paid' (upvotes) ... it is a waste of time (some times, although anyone can choose to not upvote etc), in regards to 'payment'

Is there a way , like ignored tags, to remove seeing questions from users where their rep is less than N?

Comment: Your choice on how this is answered. Do you want to block always, or to filter out when searching for it?

Comment: filter i guess... just not sure how. some questions are fine from new users but other times it feels like i read aquestion to just vote to close ...

Comment: The asker can upvote a maximum of once.  Good answers (on good questions),  can attract upvotes from many others.  Don't answer for the asker's vote, answer to attract community votes.  But as to your question, are you looking for the question's score or the user's score (rep, acceptance percentage or number, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block? No.

Though crudely you could have the search results only show you questions over a certain score:

> [score:>2 is:q](https://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a%3e2%20is%3aq)

(make sure "newest" tab is selected) but this will not update in real-time if you're used to that.